# Can Octave: Solve Linear Systems with many solutions or no solution?

Tags: octave, linear-algebra

1. Can Octave identify Linear Systems with NO solution and throw a message to that effect?
2. Can Octave 'Solve' Linear Systems that have many solutions and describe the solution set?

Here's two examples of Octave output which are not helpful to me. Is there another way to ask Octave for the desired output?

No Solution:

```
octave:13> A=[1,1,1;1,1,1] 
A =   
   1   1   1
   1   1   1   

octave:14> b=[0;1]
b =    
   0
   1

octave:15> A\b
ans =    
   0.16667
   0.16667
   0.16667
```

Infinity Many Solutions: Taken from (http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf) 2.13 (pg16).

```
octave:19> M=[2,1,0,-1,0;0,1,0,1,1;1,0,-1,2,0]
M =   
   2   1   0  -1   0
   0   1   0   1   1
   1   0  -1   2   0

octave:20> n=[4;4;0]
n =    
   4
   4
   0

octave:21> M\n
ans =    
   0.761905
   2.380952
   0.571429
  -0.095238
   1.714286

Books Solution:
{ [x;y;z;w;u] = 
  [0; 4; 0; 0; 0] + [1; -1; 3; 1; 0]*w + [0.5; -1; 0.5; 0; 1]*u | w,u (R) 
}
OR
{ (w+(0.5)u, 4-w-u, 3w+(0.5)u, w, u) | w,u (R) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there are any built in functions that check what you want but for your first question but you can write code to check for yourself. You need to see if after putting the augmented matrix into row reduced echelon form (rref) a contradiction has occurred. You can do this by seeing if for any row, all the variables are 0 but the constant is not 0. This would mean that 0*x1 + 0 *x2 + ... 0*xn does not equal zero (a contradiction). I believe the following code checks for exactly that

```
%function [feasible, x] = isfeasible(A,b)
%checks if Ax = b is feasible (a solution exists)
%and returns the solution if it exits
%input
%A: M x N matrix representing the variables in each equation, with one equation per row
%b: N X 1 vector of the constants
%output
%feasible: 1 if a solution exists, 0 otherwise
%x: N x 1 vector containing the values of the variables
function [feasible, x] = isfeasible(A,b)
  feasible = 1; %assume function is feasible
  Rref = rref([A,b]); %put the augmented matrix into row reduced echelon form
  x = Rref(:,end); %these are the values that the variables should be to solve the set of equations
  variableSums = sum(abs(Rref(:,1:(end-1))),2);
  if(any((variableSums == 0) & (abs(x) ~= 0))) %a contradiction has occurred.
    feasible = 0; %this means that 0 * all the variables is not 0
  endif
endfunction
```

As for your second question, if after putting the augmented matrix [A,b] into row reduced echelon form any row has more than 1 column (excluding the last column) with a non-zero value then your system of equations has more than one solution. Octave can solve for this and can characterize the set of solutions. All you have to do is rref([A,b]) and read the solution you get back.

Using rref on your example I found
rref([M,n]) =

```
      x         y         z         w         u      constant
   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000  -1.00000  -0.50000   0.00000
   0.00000   1.00000   0.00000   1.00000   1.00000   4.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   1.00000  -3.00000  -0.50000  -0.00000
```

this means

x = w + .5*u

y = 4 - w - u

z =  3*w + .5*u